# ordenar resultados de mayor a menor de una query lanzada a un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

estoy intentado obtener un kpi ordenado de mayor a menor.
Los obtengo a partir de lo siguiente:

```
df_partidos.groupby(['home']).agg({'away_score':[np.sum]}).head(10)
```

Me gustaría obtener los resultados de este kpi ordenados de mayor a menor.

He estado mirando con:

```
.sort_values( inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

Pero no he conseguido ningún resultado.
Si alguien puede echarme una mano

Comment: Debes pasar el parámetro `by` en `sort_values`, es decir: `.sort_values( 'away_score', inplace=True, ascending=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `df.sort_values()` para ordenar de forma ascendente o descendente con una o múltiples columnas

Adentro del método `sort_values()` debes asignar la columna en el argumento `by`

```
df_partidos.sort_values(by=['col1'])
```

Si deseas ordenar de forma descendente debes utilizar

df_partidos.sort_values(by='col1', ascending=False)

Si deseas ordenar con múltiples columnas entonces debes utilizar un arreglo de columnas en `by`

```
df_partidos.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'])
```

La documentación completa está [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: @César González, Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera pero me da error:  print(df_partidos.groupby(['home']).agg({'away_score':[np.sum]}).head(10).sort_values('away_score', inplace=True, ascending=False))

Comment: El error que me da es el siguiente:       raise ValueError(
ValueError: The column label 'away_score' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.

Comment: @AlejandroR el error que te está dando es bastante descriptivo. Tienes varias columnas con el mismo nombre, por lo que no es capaz de ordenar.